# Simplest way to auth to Google API (Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to add a new row to Spreadsheet every new firebase user.

So I created a function

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const GOOGLE_APIKEY = functions.config().google.apikey;

exports.saveNewGuest = functions.auth.user().onCreate((event) => { 
  const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  const request = {
    auth: GOOGLE_APIKEY, // Tryed this
    key: GOOGLE_APIKEY, // and this
    spreadsheetId: '<SPREADSHEET_ID>',
    range: 'Sheat!A:A',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
    alt: 'json',
    resource: {
      values: [[user.displayName, user.email]],
    },
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request, (err, response) => {
      // ... 
    })
  });
})
```

But I got..

> Error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

I already created **API keys** on **Credentials**

**I'm missing something ?**

Comment: API is for accessing public data .  The sheet in question will need to be set to public for it to work.

Comment: No.. even after I published, the error still happens

Comment: Is the Sheet set to public?  If its a private Google sheet you wont be able to access it using an API Key.   YOu will need Oauth2 access.

Comment: Yes, is public... `Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and edit`

Comment: apparently not or it wouldn't be requesting authentication

Comment: You can try.. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jANm8Jp6OWfP-LEi4ZuFgBdI3RrY2F35XtahT4W3ZKE/edit?usp=drive_web